# Finding child object using one of its properties in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to find a child object in JSON by one of its properties and add more properties to that object. I am not sure how to do this using JQuery (or regular javascript). For example: From the following JSON, I would like to find a category with id 123-1 and then add another category object as a child object. Thanks for your help.

**JSON:**

```
{
"result": {
    "category": 
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "cat1",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "rulename": "r1",
                    "regex": ""
                },
                {
                    "rulename": "r2",
                    "regex": ""
                }
            ],
            "category": 
                {
                    "id": "123-1",
                    "name": "cat1-1",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "rulename": "r1-1",
                            "regex": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }                
        }

}
```

}

**Javascript:**

```
function addSubCategory(catId, anotherCatObj) {
    //Step1: Find category object with catID in the existing json
    //Step3: add the supplied object as a child.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function appendCategoryTo(categories, destinationCategoryId, newCategoryToAdd){
    var success = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length && !success; i++){
        var category = categories[i];
        if (category.id == destinationCategoryId){
            category.category = category.category || [];
            success = !!category.category.push(newCategoryToAdd);
        } else if (category.category) {
            success = appendCategoryTo(category.category, destinationCategoryId, newCategoryToAdd);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

you have to start at the `obj.result.category` node in order to take advantage of the recursive ability, but you can easily wrap that method in another that makes it more polite.

but, as-is, here's an example usage:

```
appendCategoryTo(o.result.category, '123-1', {
  id: '123-1-1',
  name: 'cat-1-1-1',
  rules: []
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Which adds a new `category` property to the nested category as an array (i assume this follows the nomenclature) then adds the element to that new array--thus giving you:

```
{
  "result": {
    "category": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "cat1",
        "rules": [
          {
            "rulename": "r1",
            "regex": ""
          },
          {
            "rulename": "r2",
            "regex": ""
          }
        ],
        "category": [
          {
            "id": "123-1",
            "name": "cat1-1",
            "rules": [
              {
                "rulename": "r1-1",
                "regex": ""
              }
            ],
            "category": [              // BEGIN new addition
              {
                "id": "123-1-1",
                "name": "cat-1-1-1",
                "rules": [

                ]
              }
            ]                          // END new addition
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example to play with on jsfiddle, btw: http://jsfiddle.net/cqRzX/

Comment: What is the purpose of !!? Isn't it same as not using that? Thanks.

Comment: @M99: [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns an integer value representing the number of elements in the array after the push. `success` is a boolean. So, to keep a boolean value, I use `!!`. Basically, it's like `!(!0))` which means false and `!(!1))` which means true. (first `!` makes it a boolean result (but inversed) and the second gives me the boolean result (actual).

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the very quick response.